# How to set a class for all words starts with "#" in tinymce?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, tinymce

I want to set a new class to all words in tinymce while user types into tinymce. I couldn't achieve a perfect solution yet. The code I tried so far is given below. I want to create # tagging feature (like in twitter and facebook) in my website.

NB: To add the class, the word must be wrapped inside an a tag with the new class name

```
function createArticleKeyUp(ed,e)//ed is the tinymce editor, e is the keyup event
    {
        if(e.keyCode==32){//only check for the space key

            var strHtml = ed.getContent();//get content of tinymce ie html content
            var str=$(strHtml).text();//html stripped out
            str=str.replace("&nbsp;"," ");
            str=str.replace(/\n/g, "");
            $.each(str.split(" "),function(index,val){
                var isStartsWithHash=val.indexOf("#") == 0;
                if(isStartsWithHash)
                {
                    var newstrHtml=strHtml.replace(val,"<a class='newClassToset'>"+val+"</a>");

                    ed.setContent(newstrHtml);
                    ed.selection.select(ed.getBody(), true); // this is to set cursor at the end
                    ed.selection.collapse(false);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the grammar for a "word"? Is it `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`? Or do you need Unicode support?

Comment: I would build the `newstrHtml` first alone. Then call `ed` methods (setContent ...) once.

Comment: @nhahtdh unicode support for #tag may not be needed. But all other text   can be from different languages.

Answer (score 0):

All WORDS that start with a # symbol?

```
(?<=\s)#\w+
```

Comment: I get errors. Lookbehind is not supported in JavaScript